# Edit history messed up when improving a suggested edit

Tags: bug, suggested-edits

I've noticed recently that about half the time when I improve a suggested edit and then check the post's edit history, the two edits (mine and the suggested one) have been swapped around, with my edit as the last but one and the suggested edit as the latest (though it no longer matches the actual post).

For example, see [this suggested edit](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/73427). I followed up with some additional fixes, yet the post's [edit history](https://superuser.com/posts/536075/revisions) shows the suggested edit as the last one. Consequently, the diffs are also incorrect.

This looks like a bug to me. I'm guessing that the edits are ordered by the timestamp and when improving a suggested edit, both revisions are submitted at the same time. But then why doesn't it happen all the time?

Comment: I want to second this. Here is [another example](http://superuser.com/posts/542542/revisions)

Comment: And here is a [third one](http://superuser.com/posts/541656/revisions).